# Algolia instantsearch age rangeslider base on date of birth

Tags: algolia

I'm currently trying to use the instantsearch.js "rangeslider" widget to create a Age range slider from the date of births inside my index data.
Checked the documentation and seems like theres no transform data function i can use to transform the date of births into numeric age numbers like what the "hits" widget
can do.

One way i thought of was to create a age column in index and run a cron job daily to update the age column for every record base on the date of births, but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

I was wondering is there any workarounds or existing solutions for this scenario ?

Solution with [Laravel as backend](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel) (Credits to Jerska):

```
public function getAlgoliaRecord()
{
    /**
     * Load the categories relation so that it's available
     *  in the laravel toArray method
     */

    $this->dob_timestamp = strtotime('01-01-2100') - strtotime($this->dob);

    return $this->toArray();
}
```

In the frontend:

```
function _calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
        var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
        var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    }

 search.addWidget(
            instantsearch.widgets.rangeSlider({
                container: '#age',
                attributeName: 'dob_timestamp',

                tooltips: {
                    format: function(formattedValue) {

                        var dob = new Date((4102444800-formattedValue)*1000);
                        var age =_calculateAge(dob);
                        return age;
                    }
                }

            })
    );
```

CSS:

```
.ais-range-slider--value{ display:none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution involving running a cron every day would indeed work, but I think you can do this in a way easier fashion.

You could simply index numeric timestamps for your dates and add them to the `attributesForFaceting`. You'll probably want to index something like `timestamp('01-01-2100') - timestamp(birthdate)`, otherwise your slider would be older on the left, younger on the right.

Once you've done that, you can use this attribute as the main parameter of the [`rangeSlider` widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#rangeslider).
You could then use `options.tooltips` to transform this timestamp in an actually displayable age, hide with CSS the legend values (`.ais-range-slider--value`) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Never thought of using timestamps, thanks your solution works wonderful !
Updated my question with solution.